# How I can get real xmpp messages in akka-camel consumer actor?

Tags: xmpp, apache-camel, akka

I wrote an actor like this:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor,Props,ActorLogging}
import akka.camel.{CamelMessage,Consumer}

class XmppConcumer(jid:JID) extends Actor
    with Consumer with ActorLogging {

    def endpointUri = s"xmpp://${jid.login}@${jid.host}/${jid.resource}?password=${jid.password}"

    def receive = {
        case msg:CamelMessage => ???
    }
}
```

but the CammelMessage contains just a body (a string with message>body tag) of XMPP's message-stanza with some standard headers; but my message stanza was customized with some tags and attributes. How can I gain access to the real stanza's data?

Comment: Are you able to consume the full message just using the XMPP Camel Component? Maybe the component does not support what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The akka-camel component don't let you access to camel's message instance (`org.apache.camel.Message`) - see [akka-camel](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-camel/src/main/scala/akka/camel/CamelMessage.scala#L164) source - ; then I can't cast it to `org.apache.camel.component.xmpp.XmppMessage`. In the result I can't access to smack's message instance.

camel's message isn't immutable; I think because of this the akka's `CamelMessage` hasn't any ref to camel's message instance.